# JQuery AJAX always returning a false value

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Hi i wrote an ajax call in my view (MVC 4.0 C#) which displays whether the particular loan number already exists in database or not. I did the debugging for my method in controller, it's returning true if the given loan number is already existing in database, otherwise it returns false. But the ajax function always displaying the false value.

Please help me out from this.

Comment: I have one thing in my mind right now: You need `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` when using Json with HTTP GET (like `Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`).  
For more support please include all affected code pieces (Controller, View).

Comment: @lmre Gabor: Thanks Gabor, i got this solved the mistake i made was the ajax returns string True value, i am comparing the return value with a boolean. I fixed that by comparing with "True" instead of true.

Answer (score 0):

use from [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with this setting,

```
var data = {
        param1: 'A',
        param2: 'B'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url to call the controller method',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // your code here
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // your code here
        }
    });
```

before test that please clear your browser cache.